# Deserialize XML doc to .NET list

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization

I have a XML doc that looks like this:

https://gyazo.com/87aef26804136ee0cac49cf8b529f9cd

https://gyazo.com/aeb8c56689da52c67afe9b0bf7c19348

How can I convert this to an .NET List object?

I have tried this:

**Deserialization Code:**

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
{
    List<Person> result = (List<Person>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

**Person class:**

```
public class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int client_id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string  last_name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phone_office { get; set; }
    public string phone_mobile { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime createad_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
    public bool isFromHighriseOrHarvest { get; set; }
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<people type="array">
-<person>
<author-id type="integer">543801</author-id>
<background>Vi är har jobbat ihop och är vänner / Nathalie</background>
<company-id type="integer">81499881</company-id>
<created-at type="datetime">2011-08-10T08:39:45Z</created-at>
<first-name>Per</first-name>
<group-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
<id type="integer">81500134</id>
<last-name>"Cromwell" (Eriksson)</last-name>
<owner-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
<title>ägare, grafiker</title>
<updated-at type="datetime">2011-08-16T08:17:43Z</updated-at>
<visible-to>Everyone</visible-to>
<company-name>Studio Total</company-name>
<linkedin-url nil="true"/>
<      avatar_url>https://secure.highrisehq.com/avatar_proxy/eJxj4Yhmz2SWLWTMZHk2_TYLABiEBDM|9d29b49d8f165ff33f28b7f7fac2926eb8487319</avatar_url>
-<contact-data>
-<web-addresses type="array">
    -<web-address>
        <id type="integer">70306124</id>
        <location>Work</location>
        <url>http://www.studiototal.se</url>
    </web-address>
</web-addresses>
<twitter-accounts type="array"/>
-<email-addresses type="array">
    -<email-address>
    <address>per@studiototal.se</address>
  <id type="integer">39720318</id>
  <location>Work</location>
  </email-address>
  </email-addresses>
  <addresses type="array"/>
  -<phone-numbers type="array">
  -<phone-number>
  <id type="integer">70306123</id>
  <location>Work</location>
  <number>0703689909</number>
  </phone-number>
  </phone-numbers>
  <instant-messengers type="array"/>
  </contact-data>
  </person>
  -<person>
  <author-id type="integer">848257</author-id>
  <background/>
  <company-id type="integer">153838696</company-id>
  <created-at type="datetime">2013-02-18T12:49:37Z</created-at>
  <first-name>"Kristofer"</first-name>
  <group-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
  <id type="integer">153838730</id>
  <last-name>"Malmer"</last-name>
  <owner-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
  <title>Projektledare Online listening</title>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2013-02-18T12:49:37Z</updated-at>
  <visible-to>Everyone</visible-to>
  <company-name>Santa Maria</company-name>
  <linkedin-url nil="true"/>
  <avatar_url>https://secure.highrisehq.com/avatar_proxy/eJxj4Yhmz2SWLWTMZOlK0eYEABUgAvk|d7e22f72a1a3ae2efa83df54e4184d429120cd9f</avatar_url>
 -<contact-data>
 <web-addresses type="array"/>
  <twitter-accounts type="array"/>
  <email-addresses type="array"/>
  <addresses type="array"/>
  -<phone-numbers type="array">
  -<phone-number>
  <id type="integer">129346649</id>
  <location>Work</location>
  <number>031-674151</number>
  </phone-number>
  </phone-numbers>
  <instant-messengers type="array"/>
  </contact-data>
  </person>
  -<person>
  <author-id type="integer">848257</author-id>
  <background/>
  <company-id type="integer">151848665</company-id>
  <created-at type="datetime">2013-02-01T10:14:27Z</created-at>
  <first-name>"Sorush"</first-name>
  <group-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
  <id type="integer">151848627</id>
  <last-name/>
  <owner-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
  <title/>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2013-02-01T10:16:29Z</updated-at>
  <visible-to>Everyone</visible-to>
  <company-name>Rancold</company-name>
  <linkedin-url nil="true"/>
<avatar_url>https://secure.highrisehq.com/avatar_proxy/eJxj4Yhmz2SWLWTMZNnMxssJABRuAqY|1606d5054fb0e0f0b5ccc657dffcd80966ab9b64</avatar_url>
 -<contact-data>
  -<web-addresses type="array">
  -<web-address>
  <id type="integer">127911276</id>
  <location>Work</location>
  <url>http://www.rancold.com</url>
  </web-address>
  </web-addresses>
  <twitter-accounts type="array"/>
  -<email-addresses type="array">
  -<email-address>
  <address>sa@rancold.com</address>
 <id type="integer">76736018</id>
 <location>Work</location>
 </email-address>
 </email-addresses>
 <addresses type="array"/>
-<phone-numbers type="array">
 -<phone-number>
<id type="integer">127911275</id>
 <location>Work</location>
 <number>031-7441284</number>
 </phone-number>
</phone-numbers>
<instant-messengers type="array"/>
</contact-data>
</person>
```

The error is `System.InvalidOperationException.
Additional message: there is something wrong with your xml document (2, 2)`.

Comment: Include a small sample of your XML file here (one or two nodes should be sufficient). Also, include your Person class. Not links to other sites, but in the body of your question.

Comment: i have problems pasTING THE XML TO THE QUESTION. IT DOSENT LOOK TO GOOD

Comment: Post just the xml text.  Not a video or picture.

Comment: use the icon with the arrows <>, or post xml at website but just the text.

Comment: Skip a line, indent by four spaces, it'll give you a code block. It should look fine. Please post the *full* XML as well as the full details of the exception - Visual Studio should give you an option to copy the exception details to the clipboard.

Comment: so i have done it now.

Comment: can you guys help me now? :)

Comment: You have no closing people tag, is that a typo? Also, your deserialisation object needs to have People as a list property, but your object doesnt, try removing the people tag altogether and trying that.

Comment: You're either going to have to create a People struct to hold an array/list of Person and then deserialize, or amend the XML as suggested above by @ChrisWatts. It can help, for debugging purposes, to serialize your model first to see what gets output as XML, then you should be able to see why your existing XML does not get DEserialized correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should annotate your Person type and its members with XML serialization attributes. See [Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your C# class codefile automatically based on your data. First, clean up your XML (extra whitespace on `<      avatar_url>`, adding the final end tag, getting rid of the stray `-` characters...

Given good XML, save to a file, and execute the following from a VS command prompt:

```
xsd.exe people.xml
```

This creates an XSD file from the XML. Then you need to create your code file:

```
xsd.exe /c people.xsd
```

Now you have a C# codefile which has everything configured properly. You can modify this codefile for your needs, but leave all of the attributes and other XML-related stuff alone.

Comment: >xsd.exe
Command "xsd.exe" is not valid.
>               this is what i get

Comment: Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt (Start Menu and type "prompt" and you should find it there - it's called different things in different Visual Studio versions. Or search your hard drive for xsd.exe to see where it is, and call it with the full path. Don't use the Command window in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            Person.people = doc.Descendants("person").Select(x => new Person()
            {
                id = (int)x.Element("author-id"),
                client_id = (int)x.Element("company-id"),
                first_name = (string)x.Element("first-name"),
                last_name = (string)x.Element("last-name"),
                email = (string)x.Descendants("email-addresses").FirstOrDefault(),
                phone_office = x.Descendants("phone-number").Where(y => (string)y.Element("location") == "Work").Select(z => (string)x.Descendants("number").FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault(),
                phone_mobile = x.Descendants("phone-number").Where(y => (string)y.Element("location") == "Mobile").Select(z => (string)x.Descendants("number").FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault(),
                fax = x.Descendants("phone-number").Where(y => (string)y.Element("location") == "Fax").Select(z => (string)x.Descendants("number").FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault(),
                title = (string)x.Element("title"),
                createad_at = (DateTime)x.Element("created-at"),
                updated_at = (DateTime)x.Element("updated-at"),

            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public static List<Person> people = new List<Person>(); 
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int client_id { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone_office { get; set; }
        public string phone_mobile { get; set; }
        public string fax { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public DateTime createad_at { get; set; }
        public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
        public bool isFromHighriseOrHarvest { get; set; }
    }
}
```